# browser tab wise session creation using JSP ans Servlets example

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

Recently I got a requirement for browser's tab based session management in plain old JSP and Servlets. I have searched a lot by googling here and there found some  solutions which are not working and most of the solutions are present in Other than Java Programing language.

could you please provide me, sample demo application which could help me to enhance it and use for My web Application requirements.

Comment: What exactly is "browser's tab based session management"?

Comment: @AlanHay Thanks for intervention, I have seen all the threads which are discussing regarding "one browser tab = one session". Everyone is explaining the approach but All are not satisfactory as far as this is a complex scenario  the concern being Java Developer. because the implementation is shown suggesting either in .Net and HTML or just they mentioned theory what implement and how it could be achieved but I need the full-fledged example using JSP and Servlets. the user should not copy the same URL into other tab of browsers instead it should be redirected to login page this my requirement?